# Theme switch has caused buttons to stretch?

Tags: android

I was using `Theme.Light.NoTitleBar` but switched to `Theme.Holo.Light` as I needed to use the action bar.

However I've just spotted a few of my buttons have been stretched. They are standard buttons with a custom background and xml to change color when pressed. This is the xml for the button:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/logOutBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/logout_btn" />
```

It is in a relative layout. The actual backgrounds are 50px x 50px. The weird thing is I have a couple of identically laidout buttons that are 75px and 100px square and they are fine. Its just these smaller ones that are getting distored/stretched. It is showing in the design view in eclipse and on the physical device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thought I'd answer my own question here as I couldn't find any other questions relating to this issue.

I spotted that the theme switch had set a min width and min height on my buttons. I don't think I had one before. But it had switched the min width to 64dip when the height was 48dip in my particular case. I was able to switch this back to 48dip for the XML defined buttons and that solved it. So the XML looks like this now:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/logOutBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:minWidth="48dip"
            android:background="@drawable/logout_btn" />
```

For the buttons created in tables I used:

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(48, 48);
myButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: I've had the same issue, any idea where it has come from? Exact same values only mine was from switching to Theme.AppCompat.Light

Comment: I'm not sure, I think it could be an eclipse issue is my best guess!

Comment: Okay I've found out that all the design guidelines came into place around Android 3.0, so the AppCompat themes and above apply min-height's by default as part of the design guidelines. You can simply override them as you state.